# Check if any index of an array .key has a condition - js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects like this:
The code should explain what I want to achieve, is this possible/what is the smartest way to do this?

```js
var allInfo = [
  {id: "253", name: "Olaf"},
  {id: "264", name: "Hermann"},
  {id: "296", name: "Jamie"},
  {id: "237", name: "Sophie"},
  {id: "854", name: "Hanni"}
];


document.write(syncDB(allInfo, "545");
 
function syncDB(allInfo, idToCheck) {
if (idToCheck != "in any of this allInfo[].id)" {
allInfo.push(id: idToCheck, name: "");
return "just created a new index";
}
else if (idToCheck == "in any of this allInfo[].id") {
return "this id already exists";
}

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I modified your syncDB function.

```js
var allInfo = [{
  id: "253",
  name: "Olaf"
}, {
  id: "264",
  name: "Hermann"
}, {
  id: "296",
  name: "Jamie"
}, {
  id: "237",
  name: "Sophie"
}, {
  id: "854",
  name: "Hanni"
}];

document.write(syncDB(allInfo, "237") + "<br/>");
document.write(syncDB(allInfo, "545") + "<br/>");

function syncDB(allInfo, idToCheck) {
  // Grab all ids first
  const ids = allInfo.map(o => o.id);

  if (!ids.includes(idToCheck)) {
    allInfo.push({
      id: idToCheck,
      name: ""
    });
    return "just created a new index";
  } else {
    return "this id already exists";
  }

};
```